# Why is this code faster when iostream is included?

Tags: c++

Faster code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

long fib(int num)
{
   if (num <= 1)
       return 1;
   else
       return fib(num-1) + fib(num-2);
}
int main()
{
    long res = fib(45);
    printf("%li\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

Slower code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long fib(int num)
{
   if (num <= 1)
       return 1;
   else
       return fib(num-1) + fib(num-2);
}
int main()
{
    long res = fib(45);
    printf("%li\n", res);
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference between the two is the second line `#include <iostream>`.

Both are compiled with clang++ 8.0.0-3, with the -O2 flag.

```
clang++-8 -O2 fib.cpp && time ./a.out    # 3.59s
clang++-8 -O2 fib_io.cpp && time ./a.out # 3.15s
```

Edit:
It seems that the behavior changed after rebooting, with the iostream version being slower this time, which would make more sense.
I'm inclined to say that it was just a fluke, since I can't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195393/discussion-on-question-by-kitegi-why-is-this-code-faster-when-iostream-is-includ).

Comment: @BhargavRao Which excluded me from further participation at all, but well :-P ...

Comment: Just tried on Xeon E5-2650 v3: the code **without** `iostream` is faster.

Comment: Without compiler optimizations the result makes more sense: https://godbolt.org/z/PNRYK_. But why

Comment: Flaky tests and irreproducible behaviour. Voting to close.

Comment: @Attersson I'll have to agree, since I can't seem to reproduce it myself, anymore.

Comment: It makes more sense now

Answer (score 2):

When you include `#include <iostream>`, there is at least one side-effect: an instance of `std::ios_base::Init` will have to be constructed and destructed (see C++ draft [[ios.init]p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/ios.init)):

> The class `Init` describes an object whose construction ensures the construction of the eight objects declared in `<iostream>` ([iostream.objects]) that associate file stream buffers with the standard C streams provided for by the functions declared in `<cstdio>`.

An explanation about it from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init):

> This class is used to ensure that the default C++ streams (`std::cin`, `std::cout`, etc.) are properly initialized and destructed. The class tracks how many instances of it are created and initializes the C++ streams when the first instance is constructed as well as flushes the output streams when the last instance is destructed.
>
> The header `<iostream>` behaves as if it defines (directly or indirectly) an instance of `std::ios_base::Init` with static storage duration: this makes it safe to access the standard I/O streams in the constructors and destructors of static objects with ordered initialization (as long as `#include <iostream>` is included in the translation unit before these objects were defined)

This does not necessarily mean performance should be different (either better or worse). However, it means that your two programs are *not* equal, from the C++ Standard point of view.

Without looking at the actual implementation in a given standard library (or profiling it), we cannot know the detailed reason (feel free to do so and add an answer!).

Inspecting the generated code from clang on a Linux box (which seems to be your case), i.e. `libstdc++`:

```
_GLOBAL__sub_I_a.cpp:             # @_GLOBAL__sub_I_a.cpp
        push    rax
        mov     edi, offset std::__ioinit
        call    std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        mov     edi, offset std::ios_base::Init::~Init() [complete object destructor]
        mov     esi, offset std::__ioinit
        mov     edx, offset __dso_handle
        pop     rax
        jmp                 # TAILCALL
```

Therefore, either `std::ios_base::Init::Init()` or `__cxa_atexit` have some side-effect that make the overall program faster for you.

Comment: "Some side effect that make the overall program faster" is unfortunately too vague...

Comment: @Attersson I have no time to dig into `libstdc++` at the moment -- feel free to do so and provide a better answer, as I said in the answer :-) However, this does answer why it might be different. The key is that `iostream` is not a header that has no side-effect (unlike most headers).

Comment: we knew that there is some extra function. the question is why it is faster with extra function

Comment: Sorry if I came up as confrontational. You put up a nice description. Unfortunately it is not an answer. I believe it is still nice to have.

Comment: I've tested both versions on Core i7-4770 and Xeon E5-2650 v3. With `-O2` the results are opposite, with `-O3` the timings are the same.

Comment: @oblivion Yes, of course there *is* some difference, at least for OP -- that was the question, after all. No one had provided an answer as to *what* yet. Further, this likely depends on a particular standard library (or compiler, or flags...). This answers deals with the reason why `iostream` is not a side-effect free header, according to the C++ Standard, which *is* an answer on the C++ side of things.

Comment: @Evg Yeah that happens for me too but i don't get why.. even though the actual machine code for both appears to be the same..

Comment: @Xosrov, see Attersson's explanation in the chat. It is quite reasonable: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46571601#46571601